# Remove &nbsp; if there are more than 10

Tags: javascript, html, regex, ckeditor

I want to allow only a maximum of 10 `&nbsp;` between any two words and remove the remaining `&nbsp;`. How can I do this in JavaScript with a regex?

Comment: Maybe the simplest is to remove all the spaces if there are more than 10, then add 10

Comment: If we supposed that you want 2 spaces only "This is mostwondefulthinintheworldIhavebeenseen" Did the previous quote demonstrates what you want to have?

Comment: Sorry, are you looking to match either/both ` ` and `&nbsp;` or are you just using `&nbsp;` to avoid confusion(!)?

Answer (score 2):

```
str.replace(/\ {11,}/g, "          ");
```

Comment: `str.replace(/( {10}) +/g, '$1')` but that's neither `&nbsp;` nor ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
str.replace(/(\ {10})\ */g, "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Regex for this requirement. We are going to use the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method of the JavaScript String object in a simple function as follows:

```
function firstTen(txt){
arr = txt.split(" ");
out = '';
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
if (i < 10){
out += arr[i]+" ";
}
else{
out += arr[i];
}
}
    return out;
}
txt = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Apple Egypt Africa"
    alert(firstTen(txt));​
```

The following is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/KMQAV/

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a variable with 10 `&nbsp;`'s

```
for (var spaces = '', i = 0; i < 10; i++) spaces += '&nbsp;';
```

then I would use it as replacement in the following regex(p)

```
str = str.replace(/([^\s])?(\s|&nbsp;){11,}(?=[^\s]|$)/g, '$1'+spaces)
```

Here's the breakdown of the the pattern:

```
([^\s])?          # 0 or 1 character other than white space
(\s|&nbsp;){11,}  # any white space or &nbsp; used more than 10
(?=[^\s]|$)       # followed by a character other than a white space
                  # or it is the end of string
```

**EDIT:** I replaced the word boundary characters (`\b`) in the pattern because it did not match unicode character boundaries.